# C#: Should Streams be closed/disposed in called method?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a method that I am writing in C# which accepts a string which contains an XML document, and an array of streams that are XSDs.  The string document is validated against the XSDs:

```
private static XmlValidationResult ValidateDocumentInternal(string document, params Stream[] xsdStreams)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
    };

    foreach (var xsdStream in xsdStreams)
    {
        using (xsdStream)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xsdStream);

            try
            {
                settings.Schemas.Add(null, xmlReader);
            }
            finally
            {
                xmlReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    var validationErrors = new List<string>();

    settings.ValidationEventHandler += (object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs e) =>
    {
        validationErrors.Add($"({e.Exception.LineNumber}): {e.Message}");
    };

    using (var stream = document.ToStream())
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }

    return new XmlValidationResult
    {
        Success = validationErrors.Count == 0,
        ValidationErrors = validationErrors
    };
}
```

My question is, should this method be disposing of the XSD streams or should that be the responsibility of the caller?  Imagine the following code which passes in the document and XSD and expects `ValidateDocumentInternal` to dispose the XSD stream:

```
var document = GetDocument();
Stream xsd = GetXSD();
var validationResult = ValidateDocumentInternal(document, xsd);
```

or should it be like (not disposing of the stream in `ValidateDocumentInternal`):

```
var document = GetDocument();
using (Stream xsd = GetXSD()) {
    var validationResult = = ValidateDocumentInternal(document, xsd);
}
```

or alternatively should I just pass in a `bool` saying whether to dispose or not?

Comment: It might be a matter of taste but, personally, I'd prefer your second option (`using`).

Comment: I've always closed streams in the scope that they were created in, so in effect, making it the caller's responsibility rather than making it happen in the black box of a method implementation. However, some .net APIs offer a flag to take ownership of the disposal... you could also offer this as an optional parameter that defaults to false.

Comment: I normally adopt the rule "The code that creates the stream is responsible for closing it". There are some cases where this is inappropriate, for example if this would leave the stream open for a very long time. Whatever you do, it's important to document what the caller does with the stream - this is true of any parameter where the caller changes the state of the supplied object, but people often overlook that someone reading a stream is changing its state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is the caller's responsibility - it is a parameter given from the function by someone else. The function can't know if it is used in another context and and change that it will do to is is actually a "side effect"... which I personally strongly try to avoid

Comment: That seems quite sensible actually.  You can always set the position on the stream back to 0 and re-use it.

Comment: Might be true but that means that what ever code that happens after  (or worse, maybe in parallel to) this function must know that the function has a side effect. I think your second option with the using is the better practice.